# How to compile linux QT c++ on windows

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I am new to QT and I have a QT project on linux that uses a dynamic `.so` library and everything is working as expected.
I want to compile this project on QT windows to have a windows application and I have some questions.

1. Will I be able to use the same `.so` library or should I have a `.lib` one.
2. How exactly should I compile it. I saw several posts for using MinGw or the VS compiler but none were clear enough for me.
3. I am not sure if I can use the same source code or if I should have a different one for the windows version

What I tried to do is to open my project on windows QT and build it using the `MinGW 32bit` compiler but I got the following error. 
`error: cannot find windows: No such file or directory`

Comment: You cannot use .so files on windows, you have to use the Qt for windows with DLL`s. Did you already install Qt on windows or compiled it (dont recommend it)? If the code is written OS independent (which Qt makes possible) you can compile and run it. You can either use MinGW or Visual studio thats up to you.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX yes I did install QT and windows and tried to compile my project but as I stated that I had this error. My code is written OS independent but the only problem is that it uses the .so library

Comment: How do you compile? And what do you mean your code uses .so library?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I compiled it using MinGW compiler. And what I mean is that I am calling some functions from a .so library.

Comment: Yes and how did you link on linux to the .so? You have to tell the compiler to use the windows Qt DLL's to find the qt methods you are using

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I linked it using unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/HSIO/ -lMLHSIO-EL5-0_6_7. Should I have the same thing for a windows DLL library? And what about the `cannot find windows: No such file or directory` error that I had

Comment: How do you think windows will find the DLL's and headers? Search for it on the whole system? And about your error, I can't say anything without seeing how you compile your code

Comment: And should I have a DLL even if I am using the MinGW compiler?

Comment: What has the MinGW compiler to do with the DLL's?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212626/discussion-between-hasan-h-and-roquotrix).

Comment: @RoQuOTriX What do you mean when asking how do you compile your code